# jQuery get images from child divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

New to jQuery, please be gentle.

I have a structure like this:

```
<div id="stacks_in_53_page0" class="stellar_slider" style="display:     none;"> 
<div class="centered_image">
<img class="imageStyle" src="files/stacks-image-EA60B7F.png" alt="Stacks Image 56">
</div></div>

<div id="stacks_in_53_page0" class="stellar_slider" style="display: none;"> 
<div class="centered_image">
<img class="imageStyle" src="files/stacks-image-49A33E9.png" alt="Stacks Image 57">
</div></div>
```

I am able to retrieve all instances of class 'stellar_slider' easily enough but what I'm really trying to get at are the image sources contained within.

Is there an easy way to get an array of image sources starting from the 'stellar_slider'ID? I would use the img class of imageStyle itself but its not unique to this structure - it could be used on images elsewhere on the page(s).

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `each` and read all img child of stellar_slider

```
var arrayReturn=new Array();
$(".stellar_slider img").each(function(){
    arrayReturn.push($(this).attr("src"));
});
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you so much. Works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can select all images within a div with

```
$('.stellar_slider img')
```

Please note that you use the dot `.` if you are looking for a class and a hashtag `#` if you are looking for an `id`.

To get the sources, you can map through the collection above:

```
var sources = $('.stellar_slider img').map(function(){
    console.log($(this).attr('src')); // show the sources in the console
    return $(this).attr('src'); 
});
console.log(sources);
```

Now you have all images' sources in the array `sources`.

---

Depending on your usage, you might be interested in a pure javascript solution which I would prefer as I find it more clear:

```
var sources = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.stellar_slider img')).map(function(val){
    return val.getAttribute('src');
});
console.log(sources);
```

Comment: Superb. Works great. Really useful. Thank you!